# How to find the domain of a log function?

Tags: inequality

So I have this function

$f(t)=\log(t^2+5t)$

And I want to find the domain.

Now I am taking into consideration $t^2+5$ which I know needs to be greater than $0$ and $t$ that needs to be greater than $0$. And until here im good.

On the answers sheet it says that $t>0$ and that's fine.

But then it says that $t+5>0$ when $t<-5$. And that for me doesn't make any sense whatsover. I take a number that is smaller than $t$ since that's what $t<-5$ implies. E.g $-7$. Then $-7+5$ is NOT a positive number and is not greater than $0$.

I thought that t+5>0 when t>-5. Then the domain would be from (-5,0) and from (0 to inifity).

I have no idea what I am not understanding , I have dyscalulia and any simple help would be great . Thanks!

The answer that the professor told me is  (−∞, −5) ∪ (0, +∞).

Comment: Can you please fix the question? There is $f(x)$ in the left-hand side, but the variable $x$ disappears from the right-hand side. The discussion about $t+5>0$ makes me think you have $\log(t+5)$ rather than $\log(t^2+5)$.

Comment: done...............

Comment: If someone ''says that $t+5>0$ when $t<-5$'' ... it 's wrong!  And $t^2+5$  is great than zero fo all real values of $t$.

Comment: On the answers sheet is says that the domain is  (−∞, −5) ∪ (0, +∞)., becasue we do t(t+5) greater than 0....

Comment: $t^2+5t > 0$ implies what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the domain of $f(t) = \log(t^2+5)$, the part $t^2+5$ needs to be bigger than zero, that's correct.

But for any number that you fill in for $t$, a positive number will be the outcome, because it is squared. ($5^2=25, (-5)^2=25$).

If you do $t^2+5$, still all values are positive, because any positive number$+5$ will be positive.

So the domain should be $<-\infty,\infty>$.

**EDIT**

The new equation is $f(t) = \log(t^2+5t)$.

Than for every $t$: $t^2+5t>0$. 
If you set $t^2+5t=0$ to find the intersection points, than $t(t+5)=0$ and you know that $t=0$ and $t=-5$.

If you fill in any point lower, in between and above those points, you can see how the equation works.

So pick for example $t=-6$, $t=-3$, $t=3$ and fill in.

$t=-6$ --> $(-6)^2+5\times -6 = 6$ which is bigger than zero so the formula works here.

$t=-3$ --> $(-3)^2+5\times -3 = -6$ which isn't bigger than zero so the formula doesn't work.

$t=3$ --> $(3)^2+5\times 3 = 24$ which is bigger than zero so the formula works here.

And than you know, that the domain is $(-\infty, -5)\cup(0, +\infty).$

Comment: However the professor told us that the domain is  (−∞, −5) ∪ (0, +∞)., how is that possible?

Comment: Than your professor is wrong, or you gave us a wrong equation..

Comment: i am so sorry!!!! I mistyped the equation , there is another t.

Comment: I edited my answer. Do you now understand the answer of your professor or do you need more information?

Comment: I perfectly understood where you are getting the t=0 and the t=-5. But how do i put this in domain form ? Like what do these two intersection points tell me? Thanks for the patience!

Comment: Meaning, if i have these two points how should i know if the domain lies below -5 or above -5...

Comment: I edited again. Do you understand?

Comment: You are a life saver, Im reading everything you wrote slowly and carefully... i'll let you know in 5 minutes thanks!

Comment: I understood! Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1):

$$f(t) = \log(t^2+5t)$$

You need the argument of the logarithm to be positive. Hence, you have

$$t^2+5t > 0$$

$$t(t+5) > 0$$

For a product to positive, either both factors are positive or both are negative. (This is an alternative to the other procedure posted.)

Case $1$:

$$t > 0 \quad t+5 > 0$$

$$t > 0 \quad t > -5$$

For $t > 0$, both conditions are true, so the factors are positive.

Case $2$:

$$t < 0 \quad t+5 < 0$$

$$t < 0 \quad t < -5$$

For $t < -5$, both conditions are true, so the factors are negative.

Hence, the domain becomes $(-\infty, -5)\cup(0, +\infty).$

Comment: great! i got it... so its fair to say that in order to write the domain i need to take into consideration both situations... so when they are both negative and both positive... so i include in the domain both circumstances...

Comment: Exactly! Of course, the other methods involving the graph of the equation are also good, but I felt noting this would be good since you could solve it this way without using quadratics.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, its hard for me to understand even the simplest things but with simple and clear help from you guys it really really helps me. thank you !!

Comment: It is always a pleasure to help!

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\log t$ is defined for $t>0$. When you have $\log(\langle\textit{expression}\rangle)$, you have to set
$$
\langle\textit{expression}\rangle>0
$$
in order to find where $\log(\langle\textit{expression}\rangle)$ is defined. In your case the condition becomes
$$
t^2+5t>0
$$
Now we have to analyze this inequality; it factors as $t(t+5)>0$, which is satisfied when both factors are positive or both are negative.

The first case happens when $t>0$ (because in this case $t+5>0$ too).

The second case happens when $t+5<0$ (because in this case $t<0$ too.

Thus the domain is $(-\infty,-5)\cup(0,\infty)$.

It's simpler if you graph $y=x^2+5x$, which is a convex parabola meeting the $x$-axis at $-5$ and $0$:

[image]

This way you clearly see when $y>0$, that is, for $x<-5$ or $x>0$.

Note that it's *not* $t+5>0$ when $t<-5$, but $t(t+5)>0$.

Comment: I am so sorry !! I mistyped the equation . f(t)=log(t2+5t).

Comment: @BM97 Fixed also the answer

Comment: Thank you ! the graph helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

We need to find  domain of the function $log(t^2+5t)$  for this function to be defined $(t^2+5t)>0$ therefore we can write $t(t+5)$, this gives us two  critical values ${-5,0}$, $-\infty<t<-5$ as well $t>0$ therefore answering in proper format $t$ lies in $(-\infty,-5)\cup(0,+ \infty)$